# Find out Array Length after comparison

Tags: javascript, performance

I have two arrays:

```
var A = [1,2,3,4,5]
var B = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,455,,5,,5,,5,,5,,5,,5,,5,]
```

I want to compare array A to B and return the length of matching contents. what's the fastest and most efficient way to do this in JavaScript?

```
Like Length of 
1 = 5,
Length of 2s=5
Etc...
```

Comment: Sort the arrays, then loop through them keeping a count in a third array. This is basic problem solving and something you should at least have attempted before posting this low quality question

Answer (score 1):

> return the length of matching contents

Just count them:

```
function count(arr) {
    var res = {};
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        var content = arr[i];
        if (content in res)
            res[content]++;
        else
            res[content] = 1;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Now you can compare the single counts from `count(A)` with those from `count(B)`.

Answer (score 0):

I have written code for this. Here I am sending you its fiddle.

```
var A = [1,2,3,4,5]
var B = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,,5,,5,,5,,5,,5,,5,,5,]
```

Link - http://jsfiddle.net/eawAp/1/

Comment: You should also post the code with explanation in the answer and not just link to a fiddle. The answer should also be useful without relying on external sources.

Comment: Ya. Thanks. I will follow from next onwards.